# get data from the server using WCF Windows phone 8

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8

first the server code is working well

```
//declare the target list to be the reciver

 List<string> list = new List<string>();

//at the first declare that

//then call it/


private void check(double l, double lo)

        {
            Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
            client.pbackCompleted += new EventHandler<pbackCompletedEventArgs>(pResult);
            client.pbackAsync(l, lo);

        }
        private void pResult(object sender, pbackCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            list = e.Result.ToList<string>();

        }
```

but in debugging list is still null ?
and the function pResult as it is not here ?

how can i return the list and assign it to my list on the device code?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this directly, it worked for me

```
{
Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
client.pbackAsync(l, lo);
client.pbackCompleted += pResult;
}

void pResult(object sender, pbackCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    list = e.Result.ToList<string>();
}
```

Comment: It does not work 
how it can work and you delete the variable i will receive the data in

Comment: you can take the variable and see what is result in it, I just commented the code, please check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all, It works as i write in my problem, so there is no problem from the beginning.
May be its microsoft  SDK.

@Hitesh Salian thanks a lot. thanks for your try, At real when it didn't work i tried your answer but didn't work.

then suddenly nothing change and the code worked.